# How to work with variable in namespace

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I think I hvae a fundamental misunderstanding of namespace and/or static variable. But I have tried this test code (typed by hand, forgive typos)

test.h:

```
namespace test{
   static int testNum=5;
   void setNum(int value);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <test.h>

int test::setNum(int value){
   testNum=value;
}

int main(){
    test::setNum(9);
    cout<<test::testNum;
}
```

when I run this I get the value 5, not 9 as I would have expected.  It seems almost as if I have two instances of the testNum variable, but that seems to be the exact opposite of what static should be doing.  I'm guessing I've made a mistake in assuming that these features were identical to their java equvilants somehow...

I also get an error stating that testNum is declared multuple times if I remove the static from my declaration of testNum, could someone explain why that is the case as well?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know how `#include` works? It copy-pastes the content of the specified file. And is the `setNum` definition really in `main.cpp` too?

Comment: I didn't show it, but I do have the standard ifNDEF DEF in my .h.  besides, since I only include it *once* in the entire program it still wouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: Do you use `using namespace test`?

Comment: You sure you're only including it once?

Comment: Please show the real code. If there isn't a another file including `test.h` you wouldn't get multiple definition errors. Also `cout<<testNum` should presumably be `cout<<test::testNum`

Comment: `testnum` should be undefined in `main` according to the code you posted, so something is missing.

Comment: You should **copy** the actual code to the question. Else you are introducing additional errors that modify the problem altogether. The code above does not compile. I am voting to close the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First, your misunderstanding has **nothing** to do with namespaces, it's only about `static`. For the rest of this answer I'm going to refer to simply `testNum` because the fact it's in a namespace is irrelevant.

I'm also assuming you have another file, probably called `test.cpp`, which also includes `test.h` and defines the `setNum` function.

When a variable or function at namespace-scope (i.e. not a class member or local to a function) is declared `static` it means the entity's name is internal to that file. Formally it has "internal linkage", meaning it can't be referred to by name or linked to from other files (it can be indirectly referred to through a pointer or by passing it as an argument to another function.) That means if several files define `static int testNum` then each file has its own internal variable with that name, distinct from the `testNum` in every other file (in fact one file could have `static int testnum` and another could have `static double testnum` and another `static char* testNum`, they'd all be distinct and internal to each file.)  If you put a definition like that in header then *every file that includes the header has its own `testNum`*.

So with `static` on your variable in a header you have a *different* variable called `testNum` in every file that includes `test.h`. That means if you set `testNum` in one file and call a function in a different file which uses `testNum` it refers to a **different** variable, which just happens to have the same name.

Because of this, declaring non-const `static` variables in headers is almost always wrong.

Without `static` you would have a definition of the `testNum` variable in every file that includes `test.h`, which is not allowed: every entity must be defined once and once only in your program. The way to solve that is to *declare* the variable in the header, but not *define* it, which you do by telling the compiler the variable is `extern`:

```
extern int testNum;  // N.B. no "= 1" here
```

That tells the compiler there is a variable with "external linkage" called `testNum`, so when code refers to `testNum` it will always mean the same variable (not some name with internal linakge that is a different entity in every file.)  After declaring an `extern` variable it is your responsibility to ensure there is exactly one definition provided somewhere in the program, so in **exactly one** file (i.e. not in a header that gets included in multiple files) you define it:

```
int testNum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains my problem.  As I thought I was making a wrong assumption of how static worked from my java development, though I looked up static first and thought that c++ static ws the same...one of those situations where you see the answer your expecting I suppose.   I would really like my  real program to have the static value default to something safe no matter what (even if someone goes and changes my main.h) to ensure I don't have odd functionality.  It seems as if extern prevents me from having that gaurentee that it starts with a valid default value.  any way to ensure that?

Comment: `static` means several things in C++. For _class members_ it's similar to Java, but you don't have a class member in your program, you have non-member globals, which don't exist in Java.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about extern preventing a "default" value, or "defaulting to something safe". What's wrong with the `= 1` value I gave it in my answer?

Comment: Wouldn't I have to have the testNum=1 done in a method somewhere?  definately doable, but it feels unsafe, if someone accidentally deletes that one line in a function somewhere because they didn't realize what it did the code does Bad Things.  In my real code I'm working with function pointers and want to default to a no-op method if the pointer isn't loaded from an .SO, and I would feel safer knowing that no matter what, even if someone plays with my main function later, that I always point to my no-op function if nothing else is loaded.  It's a minor thing admittedly.

Comment: No, you define it at namespace-scope. That isn't _setting_ the variable, it's providing the definition of the variable you declared to be `extern`. The `extern` declaration is a promise to the compiler that there will be a definition somewhere in the program ... so you have to define it somewhere. However, with any glboal variables you need to be aware of the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) (in that context "static" refers to the lifetime of global variables, not to entities that use the `static` qualifier)

Comment: What about the variables declared `const`，`extern const int testnum;`?

Comment: @John, what about them? I don't know what you're asking. At namespace scope, `const` implies `static`, but the `extern` overrides that. So declaring it `extern` as my answer suggests will still do the right thing.

Answer (score 7):

`static` at namespace scope is a misnomer, and shouldn't be used.  It
means simply that the entity declared static has internal name binding;
in other words, that the same name in other translation units will refer
to a different entity, and in the case of variable definitions, that
there will be a separate instance of the variable in each translation
unit.  It has no effect on lifetime.  (*All* variables declared or
defined at namespace scope have static lifetime.)

`static` at namespace scope is also deprecated.  Don't use it.

With regards to declaring a variable in a header: prefix it with 
`extern`, and not `static`.  If a variable is declared `extern`, and
there is no initialization, the declaration is not a definition.  Of
course, in this case, you must provide a definition somewhere (in a
single source file).  Something along the lines of:

```
extern int testNum = 5;
int testNum = 5;
int testNum;          //  implicitly initialized with 0.
```

EDIT:

To clarify somewhat: there is some confusion here between lifetime and
name binding:

- an object has a lifetime (auto, static or dynamic—or temporary, or exception), and
- a name is bound to an entity; if the name is declared to be a variable, the entity is an object.

Do *not* confuse the keyword `static` with static lifetime.  (Functions
can be `static`, but functions have no defined lifetime in C++; they're
just there.)

The rules regarding these are not very orthognal.  Basically, with
regards to lifetime:

- all variables declared at namespace scope have static lifetime, always,
- variables declared at local scope have auto lifetime *unless* they are declared `static`, and
- variables declared at class scope have the lifetime of the class object which contains them, unless they are declared `static`.
  regards to lifetime.

Objects with static lifetime come into being sometime before `main`, and
live until after you return from `main`.

With regards to name binding:

- variables declared at namespace scope have external name binding,
  unless they are declared `static`, in which case they have internal
  name binding (but this use of `static` is deprecated), or if they are
  `const`, and are not declared `extern`,
- variables declared at class scope have external name binding, even if they are declared `static`, and
- variables declared at block scope have no binding.

Finally, there is the question of whether a declaration is a definition
or not.  If it is a definition, memory is allocated and the object is
(or may be) initialized.  If it is not a definition, it simply tells the
compiler that there is a definition somewhere else for the entity
(object) declared in the declaration.  In general, a variable
declaration is a definition *unless* it is declared `extern` and does
*not* have an initializer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution (I'll go test that in one second) but for my own enlightenment could you better explain what the problem is?  You said that all variables in a namespace are static, but that still leaves me to wonder why in this example my code wouldn't work since all I need is a static variable.  Are you staying that I ended up declaring two static variables with the same name each place I referenced testnum?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to make sure your code actually has problems before you post it asking what's wrong ;)

I copy/pasted and fixed your typos, and manually did the include:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace test{
   static int testNum=5;
   void setNum(int value);
}

void test::setNum(int value){
   testNum=value;
}

int main(){
    test::setNum(9);
    cout<<test::testNum;
}
```

result:

```
$ ./a.out 
9
```

What you haven't said is what else is in your program. If you have more than just main.cpp, and include your test.h, then each .cpp file will have its own copy of testNum. If you want them to share then you need all but one to mark it as `extern`.